# Calculate distance between points, keeping attributes from input files?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, proximity

I'm trying to use Generate Near Table in ArcMap to calculate distance between apartments and public transport.

It works fine since I'm getting the distance in meters, but I would also like to have the information about what the name of the station is.

I.e. from apartment A there is X meters to the nearest station, and here I would also like to have the name of that particular station. Basically another column in the table as you see in the image.

It doesn't seem like this tool allows including any attribute fields from input data.

The only solution I can figure out on my own, would be to break up my shapefile with stations into separate shapefiles, however that would be time consuming and inefficient since there are a lot of them.

[image: Result table from Generate Near Table]

Comment: You can join your data from the stations and apartments. Right click on the test table in the Table of Contents. Do one join for Apartments (IN_FID) and another join for Public Transport (NEAR_FID) matching up OBJECTIDS from the original data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that all you need to do is to use [Join Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm) between either the IN_FID (in feature ID) or the NEAR_FID (nearest feature ID) and the OBJECTIDs of your stations.

Which of IN_FID and NEAR_FID it is will depend on whether you used stations as the in or near feature class.

You could do the same to put the "names" of your apartments into the same table, if you wished.